# MWF2 RCON TOOL Communication with delphi using indyUDP

Tags: delphi, indy

Modern Warefare 2 (MWF2): is a Video game.
RCON TOOL: is a tool used to send commands to Game servers using UDP.

i am trying to send a command using indy to a server, its easy to send some string using idUDPclient but my Problem is that 
i supposed to send it in this format:

```
ÿÿÿÿrcon  "1234" kick cheater101

where :-
password quoted: "1234"
and command is : kick cheater101
```

as byte like this

```
   FFFFFFFF72636F6E2020223132333422206B69636B2063686561746572313031
```

notice that anything sent must start with FFFFFFFF
and that how it should  look  in Wireshark.. 
 [image]

the problem is i couldn't send it like the above .. i just sent like a string ..

i need to make it with indyUDP because I'm planning to test it on android.

here is my code for i am trying:

```
  function rcon(const IP: String; Port: TIdPort; const Pass, Command: String): String;
  var
  Query: TIdBytes;
  Buffer, Data:
  TIdBytes;
  Len: Integer;
  begin
  SetLength(Query, 4);
  Query[0] := $FF;
  Query[1] := $FF;
  Query[2] := $FF;
  Query[3] := $FF;
  AppendString(Query, 'rcon "' + Pass + '" ' + Command);
  SetLength(Data, 0);
  with TIdUDPClient.Create do try ReceiveTimeout := 2000;
  SendBuffer(IP, Port, Query);
  repeat SetLength(Buffer, 10000);
  Len := ReceiveBuffer(Buffer);
  if Len < 1 then Break;
  SetLength(Buffer, Len);
  AppendBytes(Data, Buffer);
  until False; finally Free;
  end; // preprocess Data as needed... Result := BytesToString(Data);
 end
```

usage!

```
 rcon('10.0.0.4', 28961, '1234', 'kick cheater101');
```

Wireshark:
 [image]

Comment: i am using Delphi XE-10
-function credits to Reemy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encountering a *DISPLAY* issue, not a *DATA* issue.  In your Wireshark screenshot, you are looking at the *raw bytes* as-is, not at the *hex formatted representation* of those same bytes.  Wireshark can show you both.

The actual bytes you are sending are fine - except that you are missing a *2nd* space character between `rcon` and the quoted password.

```
function rcon(const IP: String; Port: TIdPort; const Pass, Command: String): String;
var
  Query: TIdBytes;
  Buffer, Data: TIdBytes;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Query, 4);
  FillBytes(Query, 4, $FF);
  AppendString(Query, 'rcon  "' + Pass + '" ' + Command);

  SetLength(Data, 0);
  with TIdUDPClient.Create do
  try
    SendBuffer(IP, Port, Query);
    ReceiveTimeout := 2000;
    SetLength(Buffer, 10000);
    repeat
      Len := ReceiveBuffer(Buffer);
      if Len < 1 then Break;
      AppendBytes(Data, Buffer, 0, Len);
    until False;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
  // preprocess Data as needed...
  Result := BytesToString(Data);
end;
```

Also, in your Wireshark screenshot, it clearly shows 70 bytes being sent for each command, where the command itself is 32 bytes and the rest is 38 bytes of padding.  If the server is expecting that padding, you need to add it to your outgoing `Query`:

```
function rcon(const IP: String; Port: TIdPort; const Pass, Command: String): String;
var
  Query: TIdBytes;
  Buffer, Data: TIdBytes;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Query, 4);
  FillBytes(Query, 4, $FF);
  AppendString(Query, 'rcon  "' + Pass + '" ' + Command);
  if (Length(Query) < 70) then
    ExpandBytes(Query, Length(Query), 70-Length(Query));

  SetLength(Data, 0);
  with TIdUDPClient.Create do
  try
    SendBuffer(IP, Port, Query);
    ReceiveTimeout := 2000;
    SetLength(Buffer, 10000);
    repeat
      Len := ReceiveBuffer(Buffer);
      if Len < 1 then Break;
      AppendBytes(Data, Buffer, 0, Len);
    until False;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
  // preprocess Data as needed...
  Result := BytesToString(Data);
end;
```

Comment: it look exactly as it needed in wireshark only issue is idUDPClient sending to remote port 0 (10.0.0.4:0) no matter what i do, firewall say this process sending to remote port zero  :o
but hey 
**thank you so much this is great :) i will keep try to see what the problem**

Comment: The only way it could be trying to send to remote port 0 is if your `Port` parameter is 0 to begin with.  You can't send data to remote port 0, though.  In your example, you are sending to remote port 28961.

Comment: my usage is like this 
rcon('10.0.0.8', 28961, '1234', ('status'));  result using port 0 ..   so i had to write the port to the function like this  SendBuffer(IP, 28961, Query);  . newbie way  xD but works

Comment: I *guarantee* you that Indy will not try to send to port 0 if you specify a non-zero port value. Feel free to step through the code yourself in the debugger. Something else has to be going on.

Answer (score 1):

this works, well it will return the proper byte array (as an AnsiString, anyways)!. I used format to combine the inputs, and prepended the FFFFFFFFs

```
Function MakeKickCommand(pass, user: LPCSTR): AnsiString; //is wide strings okay
var
  Temp  : AnsiString;
  len, I: integer;
  a: integer;
Begin
  Temp:= AnsiString( format('rcon  "%s" kick %s', [pass, user]) );
  len := length(Temp);

  //set length of the result
  SetLength(Result, 4+len);

  //add FF FF FF FF
  FillChar (Result[1], 4, $FF);
  //copy the formatted string
  Move(Temp[1], Result[5], len);
End;
```

Comment: `AnsiString` is not available in Delphi on Android, though.  And `LPCSTR` is a Windows data type.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I chose AnsiString because "String" by default is a WideString, I assumed the Nulls every other byte would create a "wrong reply", does that not matter?

Comment: `String` is an alias for `UnicodeString`, not `WideString`. But yes, there would be extra nulls produced in between each character for most languages, and the server will likely interpret that wrong. However, since `AnsiString` does not exist on mobile platforms (compiler error), the correct way to code this for mobile would be to use `TEncoding.GetBytes()` to convert a `String` to a byte array.